# How do I confirm existence of all respective variables of a variable list?

Tags: variables, stata, capture, stata-macros

Similar threads have not led me to solve the following problem.

I use a local macro to specify a `varlist` with multiple variables and want to check whether each of the variables in this `varlist` exists in the dataset I use. So as to get a quick overview which variables do not exist in the dataset.

I have tried the following code so far:

```
local vlist caseid midx hidx v000-v013 v016 v021-v025 v101 v102

foreach v of local vlist {
   capture confirm variable `v'
    if !_rc {
        display in red "variable exists"
    }
    else {
        display in red "variable does not exist"
    }
}
```

The code runs through but nothing is displayed. I've also tried intentionally inserting variables in the `varlist` that do not exist in the dataset. Nothing changed.

Does anyone know how I can overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i generate the following toy variables:

```
clear 
set obs 5

local vlist caseid midx hidx v000 v013 v014 v015 v016 v021 v025 v101 v102

foreach v of local vlist { 
    generate `v' = runiform()
}
```

This works for me:

```
foreach v of local vlist { 
    capture confirm variable `v' 

    if !_rc { 
       display in red "variable `v' exists" 
    } 

    else { 
        display in red "variable `v' does not exist"
    } 
}

variable caseid exists
variable midx exists
variable hidx exists
variable v000 exists
variable v013 exists
variable v014 exists
variable v015 exists
variable v016 exists
variable v021 exists
variable v025 exists
variable v101 exists
variable v102 exists
```

If i drop a variable:

```
drop v000

(run the second loop again)

variable caseid exists
variable midx exists
variable hidx exists
variable v000 does not exist
variable v013 exists
variable v014 exists
variable v015 exists
variable v016 exists
variable v021 exists
variable v025 exists
variable v101 exists
variable v102 exists
```

If instead you define your local macro `vlist` as follows:

```
local vlist caseid midx hidx v000 v013-v016 v021 v025 v101 v102

(run the second loop again)

variable caseid exists
variable midx exists
variable hidx exists
variable v000 exists
variable v013-v016 does not exist
variable v021 exists
variable v025 exists
variable v101 exists
variable v102 exists
```

Similarly, if you add two variables `var1` and `var5` that do not exist:

```
local vlist caseid midx hidx var1 v000 v013 v014 v015 v016 var5 v025 v101 v102

(run the second loop again)

variable caseid exists
variable midx exists
variable hidx exists
variable var1 does not exist
variable v000 exists
variable v013 exists
variable v014 exists
variable v015 exists
variable v016 exists
variable var5 does not exist
variable v025 exists
variable v101 exists
variable v102 exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving your display problem aside, you could have a look at the user-written command `checkfor2`. It will give you three returns, containing a list with variables that are a) non-existing, b) existing, but with many missing and c) existing and with few missings.

Comment: I've just re-discovered that `checkfor2` (SSC) requires and builds on my `isvar` (SSC), which doesn't address missings but does separate names of variables that do exist and those that don't. `missings` (_Stata Journal_) is a later command for reporting on missings.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The checkfor2 is helpful. Additionally, using the display approach above I found out that if I just include "cap noi display "`country'" in the loop, it also does the trick, so that the output looks like what I wanted: "BF v001 exists BF v002 exists... etc"